# HTML5 Video and WebView

Tags: android, html, android-webview, html5-video

I know this has been discussed a lot, yet looking through nearly every discussion on the Internet about enabling HTML5 Video in the Android WebView, I am still unable to get it to work correctly.

Currently I have a HTML page being loaded with the WebView. It has a  tag with a source tag referencing a local mp4 video.

```
<video height="720" width="1280"><source src="vid.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

The page loads fine, and I see a big grey video placeholder. Tapping this a couple of times starts the video's audio playing. No visuals, just the audio.

I have the following in my activity:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
webSettings.setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);

webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

And I have hardware acceleration enabled in my manifest (on the application, and activity for good measure)

What else am I missing? Why can't I see the actual video?

I am using jQuery to start the video playing with "video.play()" but like I said, I can only hear the audio after tapping a couple of times.

I have even tried to implement the various "wrapper" classes dotted around, but they all seem to be broken/don't work when I implement them (although reading the docs, my code should be enough, with the chrome client and HA enabled)

Please help!

Comment: Just an FYI: video.play() will ONLY work when it's coming from an event, such as firing video.play() in an onclick event. Otherwise android will suppress it, even in a webview.

Comment: hmm, it is currently coming from a callback event from a JS library called GSAP (for animating css3, dom, canvas etc). How would I go about making the jQuery code that calls video.play(), actually play the video? (and do all the other video functions like pause() etc?)

Comment: Just to add to this, even when I click(tap) the video, only audio is apparent! So even if I figure out how to play the video, I'm concerned the audio will play but not the video, as is the main issue now.

Comment: Well, oddly enough, if from java you send to the webview a javascript command `wv.loadUrl("javascript:video.play();");` it will count as an event and video.play() will work. As far as why you're only getting audio, I don't know. Thought I would chime in on my experience with calling video.play()

Comment: Sadly, all this level of control needs to be in the HTML and JS code. I need to be able to use the video control methods from inside the HTML file, on the GSAP callbacks.

Comment: Were you able to solve this - i have a very similar problem

Comment: I ended up doing something totally different in the end. I ended up using a VideoView inside a ViewFlipper to show video, as I can start and stop the video without the need for the user to do anything.